# Angular - is it possible to toggle more than one CSS class on different conditions?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to toggle two CSS classes using different conditions:

```
  <div *ngFor="let year of years" [class.selectedYear]="year === selectedYear"
       [class.currentYear]="year === date.getFullYear()" (click)="onYearClick(year)">{{ year }} 
  </div>
```

I'm really not sure if this is at all possible though. Inside my `onYearClick()` method, I am referencing the DOM elements, which have classes `selectedYear` or `currentYear`. The `console.log` of these DOM elements returns undefined, however:

```
  @ViewChild('currentYear') currentYearDOM?: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('selectedYear') selectedYearDOM?: ElementRef;

  onYearClick() {
    console.log(this.date.getFullYear());
    console.log(this.currentYearDOM);
    console.log(this.selectedYearDOM);
```

So, I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to toggle more than one CSS class using the above mentioned template notation?
2. Why are these objects undefined? The DOM elements with the respective classes exist

=============================================

Update:
I have tried using the following statement in my div instead:

```
[ngClass]="{'selectedYear': year === selectedYear,'currentYear': year === date.getFullYear() }"
```

, but the problem remains.

I really think there is sth wrong with the way I toggle these classes:

When I first open the view, the right div, which contains the current year, is marked with the `currentYear` CSS class. Then, when I click on another year, close the view and open it again, the selected year is marked with the `selectedYear` CSS class, but the current year has lost its `currentYear` CSS class. Why would this happen?

Also: the `console.log` of my ViewChild components always prints `undefined`. So, I assume there is something wrong with the way I am trying to reference my DOM elements.

=======================================================

another update:

I found the issue: The condition for `currentYear` was just wrong. Wow, that's a bit stupid. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'class1': yourCondition1, 'class2': yourCondition2}"></div>
```